# Blazor form only submit after refresh

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I am creating a blazor application and I have a form I need to submit, once I click on the submit button it refresh the page then submit it. Which leads the model to be empty

```
@page "/user"
@page "/user/{id}"

@inject IUserService _userService;
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager;

@using AppOne.Entities.Dtos.Responses
@using AppOne.Entities.Dtos.Requests

@if (!Id.HasValue)
{
    <PageTitle>Add user</PageTitle>
    <h1>Add user</h1>

}
else
{
    <PageTitle>user Management</PageTitle>
    <h1>user Management</h1>
}


<div class="row">
    <EditForm Model="@userModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidRequest" OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidRequest" FormName="sample">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
            
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3">First Name</label>
            <InputText class="col-md-8 form-control" @bind-Value="@userModel.FirstName" id="firstName"></InputText>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">z
            <label class="col-md-3">Last Name</label>
            <InputText class="col-md-8 form-control" @bind-Value="@userModel.LastName" id="lastName"></InputText>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3">Number</label>
            <InputNumber class="col-md-8 form-control" @bind-Value="@userModel.UserNumber" id="nb"></InputNumber>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3">Date Of Birth</label>
            <InputDate class="col-md-8 form-control" @bind-Value="@userModel.DateOfBirth" id="dob"></InputDate>
        </div>
       
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Save user</button>
           
        @if (Id.HasValue)
        {
            <a @onclick="DeleteUser" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
        }
       
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>@Message</p>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter] public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    protected string Message = string.Empty;

    public GetUserResponse userModel { get; set; } = new GetUserResponse();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (Id.HasValue)
        {
            var response = await _userService.GetUserById(Id.Value);

            if (response != null)
                 userModel = response;
        }
    }

    protected void HandleInvalidRequest()
    {
        Message = "Something went wrong";
    }

    protected void ReturnToUsers()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/users");
    }

    protected async Task DeleteUser()
    {
        if (Id.HasValue)
        {
            var response = await _userService.DeleteUser(Id.Value);

            if (response)
                _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/users");
            else
                Message = "Something went wrong, please try again later";
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleValidRequest()
    {
        if (!Id.HasValue)
        {
            var request = new CreateUserRequest()
            {
                UserNumber = userModel.UserNumber,
                FirstName = userModel.FirstName,
                DateOfBirth = userModel.DateOfBirth,
                LastName = userModel.LastName
            };
            var result = await _userService.AddUser(request);
            
            if (result != null)
                _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/users");
            else
                Message = "Something went wrong, please try again later";
        }
        else
        {
            var request = new UpdateUserRequest()
            {
                UserId = userModel.UserId,
                UserNumber = userModel.UserNumber,
                FirstName = userModel.FirstName,
                DateOfBirth = userModel.DateOfBirth,
                LastName = userModel.LastName
            };
            
            var response = await _userService.UpdateUser(Id.Value, request);

            if (response)
                _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/users");
            else
                Message = "Something went wrong, please try again later";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you are overriding the `id` of the input elements, thus breaking the binding.

Comment: Net version?  This looks like Net8 submitting a form in SSR mode rather than interactive mode?

Comment: .NET 8, using the latest version

Comment: @MateusZampol tried it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have created your solution from the template with *Interactivity location* set to *Per page/component*.

Check your `App.razor`.  Does it have the `rendermode` set on `Routes` and `HeadOutlet`?

```cs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorApp3.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My guess is not and your page is server side rendering with static output.

If this is the case, you need to decide either to globally set the render mode in `App` or to set it selectively in each component/page.

In your page you need to add:

```cs
@page "/user"
@page "/user/{id}"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
```

or whatever interactive mode you want.

Comment: Am also having similar issues, after i added the render mode on those places i get an error on my page

Comment: @kyenry - this is a very common issue.  Please create a separate question with your code, providing the error you are getting.

Comment: would it be possible for you to connect with me on anydesk?

Comment: Sorry, no.  Ask your question on here.  See my comments on Marco's question.

Comment: here is my question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77711885/blazored-fluentvalidation-issue-in-blazor-server-net-8, thank you