# Blazored.FluentValidation issue in Blazor Server .NET 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I am encountering issues with Blazored.FluentValidation in my Blazor Server application while implementing login functionality. Below is my login component code:

```
<EditForm class="needs-validation" Model="@Input" OnValidSubmit="@SubmitAsync" FormName="login" novalidate>
<FluentValidationValidator @ref="@_fluentValidationValidator" />
<DataAnnotationsValidator />

<AuthInput Id="email" ErrorFeedback="" Label="Email Address"
           TextFieldType="TextFieldType.EmailAddress"
           @bind-Value="Input.Email" PlaceHolder="Email Address here"
           ValidationFor="@(() => Input.Email)" />

<AuthInput Id="password" ErrorFeedback="" Label="Password" 
           TextFieldType="TextFieldType.Password"
           PlaceHolder="********" @bind-Value="Input.Password"
           ValidationFor="@(() => Input.Password)" />

<div class="d-lg-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-4">
    <div class="form-check"></div>
    <a href="/Identity/Account/ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
</div>

<Button Text="Sign In" ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" IsFullWidth="true" />
```

My AuthInput Component

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using System.Linq.Expressions
@inherits InputBase<string>

<div class="@ColSize">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="@Id" class="form-label">@LabelText</label>
        <input id="@Id" name="@FieldName" @attributes="@AdditionalAttributes" class="form-control" type="@_type"
               required="@IsRequired" @bind="@Value" placeholder="@PlaceHolder" />
        <ValidationMessage For="ValidationFor" />
        <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
    </div>
</div>

@code{
[Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }
[Parameter] public string LabelText { get; set; }
[Parameter] public string ColSize { get; set;  }
[Parameter] public string FieldName { get; set; }
[Parameter] public string PlaceHolder { get; set; }
[Parameter] public bool IsRequired { get; set; } = false;
[Parameter] public TextFieldType TextFieldType { get; set; } = TextFieldType.Text;
[Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>> ValidationFor { get; set; } = default!;

private string _type => TextFieldType == TextFieldType.Text ? "text" :
                        TextFieldType == TextFieldType.Number ? "number" :
                        TextFieldType == TextFieldType.Password ? "password" :
                        TextFieldType == TextFieldType.EmailAddress ? "email" :
                        "text";

protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string result, out string validationErrorMessage)
{
    result = value;
    validationErrorMessage = null;
    return true;
}
}
```

In the code-behind, I've declared:

```
private FluentValidationValidator? _fluentValidationValidator;
private bool Validated => _fluentValidationValidator!.Validate(options => { 
                          options.IncludeAllRuleSets(); });
private TokenRequestModel Input { get; set; } = new();
```

Null Reference Exception:
The Validate method, as per the documentation, should not result in a null reference exception. Despite including all rule sets with options.IncludeAllRuleSets(), I'm still facing this error. Any insights into the cause or suggestions for resolution based on the Blazored.FluentValidation documentation would be appreciated.

[image: The Null Exception]

I've followed the documentation on the [Blazored.FluentValidation](https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation) source control, but these issues persist. Any help, recommendations, or code examples to resolve these Blazored.FluentValidation problems.

Comment: Have you tried with default  InputText component?The issue seems related with your AuthInput component

Comment: I did test it with that, the 2way binding works with it but i still can't get the fleuntvalidation to stop throwing the null reference exception

Comment: What is AuthInput?  Yours or someone else's control?

Comment: Also can you copy and paste the actaul exception.

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis I had updated the question with the AuthInput component code

Comment: See my answer.  I've also answered the implicit "Why doesn't my component binding work" question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two questions:

> Why am I getting a null exception?

`_fluentValidationValidator` is null until the component is first rendered: sub components [such as `FluentValidationValidator`] don't exist before the first render.

```cs
private FluentValidationValidator? _fluentValidationValidator;
```

So if you try to use `Validated` before that first render, you get an exception as there's no _fluentValidationValidator object to call `Validate` on.  `_fluentValidationValidator!` tells the compiler to ignore null validation checking because you know better and at this point in the code `_fluentValidationValidator` can't be null.  Obviously not the case here.

```cs
private bool Validated => _fluentValidationValidator!.Validate(options => { 
                          options.IncludeAllRuleSets(); });
```

You can use the *null-conditional operator* like this which returns `false` if `_fluentValidationValidator` is null.

```cs
private bool Validated => _fluentValidationValidator?.Validate(options => { 
                          options.IncludeAllRuleSets(); }) ?? false;
```

Or refactor your logic to not attempt to use `_fluentValidationValidator` until you know it's not null.

In the documentation you see this.  At this point you're submitting the form, so `_fluentValidationValidator` must exist.

```cs
    private void SubmitFormAsync()
    {
        if (await _fluentValidationValidator!.ValidateAsync())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Form Submitted Successfully!");
        }
    }
```

Personally, I don't like using the null-suppression operator unless I have to.  I prefer the belt-and-braces null-conditional operator.

> Why isn't my `AuthInput` binding working?

You can't use `Bind` as you're doing.  Within the component you need to assign the getter and the setter separately.  As you inherit from `InputBase` you need to wire these into `CurrentValueAsString` to plug into the built in `InputBase` logic.

Here's a refactored version of your component.  I've added a few comments questioning why you have certain parameters because i'm guessing you're putting them in because they exist in the BootStrap example code.  If you have valid reasons then ignore my comments.   I've also refactored nullability in places.

```cs
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using System.Linq.Expressions
@using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis

@inherits InputBase<string>

<div class="@ColSize">
    <div class="mb-3">
        @if(this.LabelText is not null)
        {
            <label class="form-label">@LabelText</label>
        }
        <input @attributes="@AdditionalAttributes" class="form-control" type="@_type"
               required="@IsRequired" value="@this.CurrentValueAsString" @onchange="this.SetValue" placeholder="@PlaceHolder" />
        <ValidationMessage For="this.ValueExpression" />
        <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    // Do you need this?
    //[Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? LabelText { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string ColSize { get; set; } = "col-12";
    // Do you need this?
    //[Parameter] public string FieldName { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string PlaceHolder { get; set; } = "Enter a value";
    [Parameter] public bool IsRequired { get; set; } = false;
    [Parameter] public TextFieldType TextFieldType { get; set; } = TextFieldType.Text;

    // Why include number - InputBase<int> if it's a integer
    private string _type => TextFieldType == TextFieldType.Text ? "text" :
                            TextFieldType == TextFieldType.Number ? "number" :
                            TextFieldType == TextFieldType.Password ? "password" :
                            TextFieldType == TextFieldType.EmailAddress ? "email" :
                            "text";

    private void SetValue(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        this.CurrentValueAsString = e.Value?.ToString() ?? null;
    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out string? result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

This page then demos the control in action:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<EditForm Model="_model" >
    <AuthInput @bind-Value="_model.UserName" LabelText="User Name" PlaceHolder="Enter your user name" />

</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>User Name: @_model.UserName</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private Model _model = new();

    public class Model {
        public string? UserName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, I have tested the code out but I still have the same binding issues, could it be because my component exists in a different namespace ?

Comment: It shouldn't matter.  Revamp your component, plug it into my code as and I'll have a look at what's wrong.  Here's a Repo of my MRE - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO77711885

Comment: I forked the project and plugged in my defective code https://github.com/kyree-henry/SO77711885 and it worked there properly i even created a class library project there to test my second component that wasn't functioning and it worked am not sure why it is not working on my main project

Comment: Or could it be that the template am using i have all the files (css, javascript, images, fonts) inside the ClassLibrary project

Comment: If your updated code works in the MRE then I can't see how anyone can help you any more.  Your missing something in you own code.

Comment: I just made some few changes to the code you provided like removing of the at sign before the onChange event and instead of `onchange=@(() => this.SetValue)` i just did `onchange="@this.SetValue"`

Comment: Again thank you very much for your help, I am very new to Blazor and decided to jump to .net8 with it since it's getting a whole lot of praise on the internet